# Oecpins.dll and ukakocon.dll errors on bootup

Tags: windows-7, dll

I get these errors every time I boot my computer:

[image]

Running Windows 7 Home...I google these and get no hits.  Anyone know what the issue is or what I can do to troubleshoot further?  I have anti-virus running and am a pretty savvy user so I don't think its a virus/malware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look like leftovers of some malware/spyware that was removed from your system, probably by your antivirus/antispyware application.

Since you say you're a pretty savvy user, I would recommend removing these RunDLL errors by modifying registry.

Open Registry Editor, scroll to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and see if you can find any startup commands related to these dlls. If so, delete them.

If they're hidden somewhere else use this tool to find a remove them. [Autoruns for Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

If you're still having this problem, try creating dummy files with these names and extensions in that location and see what happens.

Comment: Sure enough that was it - there was one in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\..\Run and one in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\..\Run, made a backup in case something screws up down the road.